# if stream().filter is empty

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, java-stream, option-type

I want to know how to execute code from a stream if the filter does not find values and finds it, an example code:

```
 @Transactional
public void change(ClassName dep){
    // code
    dep.getFoo()
            .stream()
            .filter(f -> f.getName().equals(doo.getName))
            
}
```

if the filter has a value then:

```
user.setFoo(f);
```

if there is no value in the filter then:

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
foo.setName("Exp");
user.setFoo(foo);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest creating a constructor for `Foo` accepting `name`.

You can then extract the name with default value of `Optional`:

```
Foo foo = dep.getFoo()
        .stream()
        .filter(f -> f.getName().equals(doo.getName))
        .findAny().orElse(new Foo("Exp"));
user.setFoo(foo);
```

As Holger cleverly noticed using `orElseGet` would avoid executing the `Supplier` in case the `Optional` is not empty (beneficial if the computation is complex or side effects occur):

```
Foo foo = dep.getFoo()
        .stream()
        .filter(f -> f.getName().equals(doo.getName))
        .findAny().orElseGet(() -> new Foo("Exp"));
user.setFoo(foo);
```

Since java 11 you can use `ifPresentOrElse`:

```
dep.getFoo()
        .stream()
        .filter(f -> f.getName().equals(doo.getName))
        .findAny()
        .ifPresentOrElse(user::setFoo, () -> user.setFoo(new Foo("Exp")));
```

P.S.: If you cannot create the constructor, you can just create the method to provide it and use it in the above snippet:

```
public static Foo defaultFoo() {
    Foo foo = new Foo();
    foo.setName("Exp");
    return foo;
}
```

Comment: It’s worth mentioning that you can also use `.findAny().orElseGet(() -> new Foo("Exp"))` to avoid the potentially unnecessary creation of the `Foo` instance. That’s important if `Foo`’s constructor performs expensive operations or has unintended side effects.

Comment: @Holger you're right, thank you for the advice!

Answer (score 1):

Try next example:

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
foo.setName("Exp");


user.setFoo(dep.getFoo()
            .stream()
            .filter(f -> f.getName().equals(doo.getName))
            .findFirst().orElse(foo);
```

Because filter could return more then one object, you should to limit it on one object. findFirst will return object of type Optional and orElse will return foo in case optional is empty. In other case you will get founded foo.

Comment: Note that this always creates an extra `Foo` object, so it's not the leanest solution.